# Is it necessary to add requirejs-config.js when we need to add custom js in magento 2 theme

Tags: magento2, requirejs-config.js

I have added a custom js file in my child theme and added the link in the default_head_blocks.xml. I am getting errors.

```
<link src="js/custom.js"/>

<!-- Add external resources -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" src_type="url" />
```

Is it necessary to specify the custom js in requirejs-config.js ?

Comment: try this code `<script src="js/custom.js" />` after clear cache and run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It improves perceived page load times because it allows JavaScript to load in the background. In particular, it enables asynchronous JavaScript loading